# Page jitters onload with jquery scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing a lot of "post production" with jquery and logically when the page loads it takes a few seconds more for the jquery scripts to load causing the infamous "jitter" effect. Now I'm in a special predicament. The only way for me to manipulate the HTML structure is using jQuery. I have zero access to the HTML. I've attached my jQuery code, was wondering what the best way was to speed things up a bit or make things flow better.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Remove container class from masthead
    $('#masthead').removeClass('container');

    //Move search bar to navbar
    $('#search').unwrap();
    $('.nav.navbar-nav').append($('#search'));
    $('#search').removeClass('text-right');
    $('#search').addClass('pull-right');

    //Logo size
    $('.pageLogo').children('img').css('width', '100px');

    $('.nav.navbar-nav').append('<li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle disabled" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="userdropdown">Login</span><b class="caret"</b></a><ul class="dropdown-menu profileul" role="menu"></ul></li>');

    if($('.notloggedin').length) {
        $('.profileul').append($('#internal_login_form'));
    } else {
        $('.userdropdown').text($('.user-details').html().split('<br>')[1]);
        $('.profileul').append($('.profile-menu').children('.dropdown-menu').children());
        $('.user-details').next().remove();
        $('.user-details').remove();
        $('.profileul').append($('#langSel'));
    }

$('#login_info').remove();

$('.navbar').unwrap().unwrap().unwrap();

//Add Logo to navbar header
$('.navbar-header').append($('.pageLogo'));

//Remove original container for 
$('#masthead').children().first().remove();

//Change pageLogo class to navbar-brand
$('.pageLogo').addClass('navbar-brand');
$('.navbar-brand').removeClass('pageLogo');


//Login Form
$('#login_page').children('div').remove();

//Footer
$('#footer').find('hr').remove();


//Remove glyphicon from learning path
$('.glyphicon-play').remove();

//Move forums tile on mycourse page
$('.forums').appendTo($('.col-md-4').first());

});
```

Comment: If you have access to the CSS, you can hide the `body` with `body{display:none}` and reveal it with `$('body').show()` at the end of your javascript.  You're dealing with a FOUC http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/web-designer/how-to-prevent-flash-of-unstyled-content-on-your-websites/

Comment: @RobSchmuecker this worked brilliantly. I compensate a few milliseconds in load time, but it just looks better.

Answer (score 0):

As something to try what happens if you instead of binding to `document.ready` you bind to `window.onload`.

eg: `window.onload = function() { .... }`

not sure if it will make a difference but might be worth a try.